# Use Negation to exclude lines containing `#`

Tags: grep

Suppose I have such a file:

```
    $ head -n 15 foo.md
    # User Database
    # 
    # Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system is running
    # in single-user mode.  At other times this information is provided by
    # Open Directory.
    #
    # See the opendirectoryd(8) man page for additional information about
    # Open Directory.
    ##
    nobody:*:-2:-2:Unprivileged User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
    root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
    daemon:*:1:1:System Services:/var/root:/usr/bin/false
    _uucp:*:4:4:Unix to Unix Copy Protocol:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/uucico
    _taskgated:*:13:13:Task Gate Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

I'd like to view the contents excluding line with '#',
it can be achieved by invert options like

$ grep -v "^#" < foo.md
I intend alternatively with negation `^`

```
    $ grep -E "[^#]" < foo.md
    # User Database
    # 
    # Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system is running
    # in single-user mode.  At other times this information is provided by
```

And

```
    $ grep -Eo "[^#]+" < foo.md
     User Database

     Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system is running
     in single-user mode.  At other times this information is provided by
     Open Directory.
     See the opendirectoryd(8) man page for additional information about
     Open Directory.
    nobody:*:-2:-2:Unprivileged User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

The command didn't output as I desired.

How to resolve such a problem with negation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file has spaces before the `#`, so you'll want to account for it. Negation is unnecessary here and complicates everything — especially when trying to inverse match, so don't bother with it.

```
grep -v "^\s*#" file.txt
```

**Output**:

```
nobody:*:-2:-2:Unprivileged User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
daemon:*:1:1:System Services:/var/root:/usr/bin/false
_uucp:*:4:4:Unix to Unix Copy Protocol:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/uucico
_taskgated:*:13:13:Task Gate Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

To get the opposite just lose the invert match (`-v`) option:

```
grep "^\s*#"
```

**Output**:

```
# User Database
# 
# Note that this file is consulted directly only when the system is running
# in single-user mode.  At other times this information is provided by
# Open Directory.
#
# See the opendirectoryd(8) man page for additional information about
# Open Directory.
##
```

> With your command `grep -Eo "[^#]+"` you tell grep to ***only***
>   (`-o`) match the parts of the line without **#** — so it's obviously
>   going to output everything except for the **#** character.

**POSIX Version**:

```
grep '^[[:blank:]]*#'
```

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks, I've updated the answer based on your suggestions — cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, you wish to have only the not-comment lines, the last 5 lines, without starting with '#'?

This works very well for me with grep -v "^#" on Mac OS X or on CentOS, only the last 5 lines are in the output.

Option -v means invert the match and character '^' means 'the beginning of the line'